# Add one nested record from several records at once in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I've been stuck for a few days on this and although I managed to find a few relevant answers, nothing seems to cover the two features I need altogether.

Basically I've got a "Question", and "Answer" model. I want to show as many answer fields as questions are there, and create them using my custom controller. I also want to assign either session id if not signed in, or user Id to the answer (so then I can work out who answered once they register).
I managed to show the fields, but now they won't save, only thing I get is an "internal error" message on the view and an exception on the console:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: expected Array (got Rack::Utils::KeySpaceConstrainedParams) for param `question'
```

This are what my models / controller look like:

**step1_controller.rb**

```
class Configurator::Step1Controller < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @questions = Question.includes(:choices).all()
  end

  def create
    Question.update_attributes(params[:question].keys, params[:question].values)
    flash[:notice] = 'Reports were successfully updated.'
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

**models/answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :weight, :user_id, :question_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end
```

**models/question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_at, :desc, :updated_at, :title, :created_by_id, :updated_by_id, :tag_id, :answers_attributes
  belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :updated_by, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :tag
  has_many :choices
  has_many :answers
  has_many :user, :through => :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

**routes.rb**

namespace :configurator do
    get "step1", :to => 'step1#new', :as => :step1
    post "step1" => "step1#create", :as => :step1
  end

**view**

```
<%= form_for :question, :url => configurator_step1_path do -%>
      <% for question in @questions %>
       <%= fields_for "question[]", question do |question_fields| %>
        <%= question_fields.hidden_field :id %>
        <%= question_fields.label :title, question.title %>
        <%= question_fields.fields_for :answers, [Answer.new] do |li_fields| %>
          <%= li_fields.text_field :weight %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <%= submit_tag "Create line items" %>
        <% end %>
       <% if false %>
      <%= f.fields_for :answers, [Answer.new]*5 do |li_fields| %>
      <%= li_fields.label :weight %>
      <%= li_fields.text_field :weight %>
         <% end %>
      <br>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Also in your controller instead of:

```
Question.update_attributes(params[:question].keys, params[:question].values)
```

You could do:

```
Question.update_attributes(params[:question])
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for your answer. I tried that line of code and as mine stands I still get the same problem.
I've also checked out a few videos, of nested forms as well as multiple records editing at once but none of them seems to cover both scenarios at once which is my particular case. 
Any other ideas?